# Генератор или list comprehension для iterable?

Tags: python, list

```
l = [1, 2, 3]
```

Что лучше?

```
l.extend(i for i in range(1000000))
```

или

```
l.extend([i for i in range(1000000)])
```

Когда стоит использовать list comprehension, а когда генератор, если принимаются оба варианта?

Answer (score 5):

В данном случае лучше всего:

```
l.extend(range(1000000))
```

В `Python 3` `range` - это специальный объект и под оптимальную работу с ним специально заточены многие вещи, поэтому непосредственная работа с `range` часто оказывается быстрее всего.

Если же речь именно про само сравнение генератора со списковым включением, то нужно смотреть не слишком ли большой у вас список получается (в этом случае он может съесть память и замедлить работу интерпретатора) и на то, что вы дальше делаете с полученным результатом. В данном случае для использования в `extend` разница, думаю, будет не сильно существенной.

Answer (score 5):

Замеры показывают, что по скорости разница незначительна:

```py
In [2]: %timeit l.extend(i for i in range(1000000))
80 ms ± 4.67 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

```py
In [4]: %timeit l.extend([i for i in range(1000000)])
76.8 ms ± 5.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Но при этом списковое включение полностью сохраняет массив в память. В данном случае сохранять массив в память не нужно, поэтому лучше будет использовать генератор.

Хороший пример использования спискового включения — когда Вам необходимо после генерации списка применить к нему какой-либо из стандартных методов.